# How can I play .mid file on iOS device

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, midi

I tried AVAudioPlayer it doesnt work.

```
 url= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.mid", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSLog(@"URL Description is %@",[url description]);
NSError *error=nil;
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if (error!=nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
[audioPlayer play];
```

I get this error

```
Error is The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)
```

Should I be using another method to do this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MusicPlayer+MusicSequence on ios 5

Comment: sorry, no. it was introduced in ios 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the built-in CoreMIDI framework. Docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/MIDISetup/index.html

http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/core-midi-and-friends

http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-coremidi-in-ios-example.html

Hope it helps.